# Files are not uploading into folder with move_uploaded_file(). What is wrong?

Tags: php, file-upload

I am getting irritated because this code WORKS when I am adding a post. However, when I am editing a post, this code does not want to upload the new updated image into the folder. Well it does, but it is a "broken" file that has not uploaded correctly. Why am I having these issues?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['postupdate'])) {

    $editPostTitle = trim($_POST['editposttitle']);
    $editPostAuthor = trim($_POST['editpostauthor']);
    $editPostStatus = trim($_POST['editpoststatus']);
    $editPostTags = trim($_POST['editposttags']);
    $post_image = $_FILES['editimage']['name'];
    $post_image_temp = $_FILES['editimage']['tmp_name'];
    $editPostContent = trim($_POST['editpostcontent']);

    move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "./images/".$post_image);
    print_r(error_get_last());

    $updateposts = $conn->prepare("
    UPDATE posts 
    SET post_title = ?, post_author = ?, post_tags = ?, post_image = ?, post_content = ?
    WHERE post_id = ?
    ");
    $updateposts->bind_param("sssssi", $editPostTitle, $editPostAuthor, $editPostTags, $editPostImage, $editPostContent, $editId);
    $updateposts->execute();
    $updateposts->close();



}
```

Here is an example of what I am encountering:

[image: Look at the file on the far right]

Comment: I think you have to use perfect path for image Like below
`move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp,Yii::getAlias('@webroot')."/images/".$post_image);`
path is yourproject/web/images/

Comment: check input file having File Path ($_FILES['editimage'])

Comment: i see few errors, dont know if it causes it or not, yet change them, in sql query bindparam you are passing $editPostImage which is not a variable in your script, pass $post_image as it holds the name

Comment: @Exprator I see that. The was originally the variable name. I just changed it to see if that was the issue as to why the file was not uploading and forgot to correct that.

Comment: see your log file /var/log/httpd/error_log

Comment: Ok, I figured it out everyone. Odd enough, it was because of a bootstrap class attribute. I mean, really?

Answer (score 0):

Ok everyone, oddly enough, it was because of a bootstrap class attribute I added.

Here was the problem:

```
<input type="file" name="editimage" id="editimage" class="form-control"/>
```

I had to remove this:

```
class="form-control"
```